# Applying Active Directory authentication to Power BI report server

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I just deployed a Power BI report server on SQL Server 2017  which is working at Windows Server 2016. The *server* is running on my local network. Which mean it does not have a domain. Is it possible to apply AD authentication in this case? (The Azure AD has already been created, and I just want to apply it to the report server.)

I had read the following document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/mobile/mobile-oauth-ssrs

But I think this cannot help in the local network case since it requires a domain.

Comment: Power BI Report server eventually leads here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/authentication-with-the-report-server?view=sql-server-ver15. Your best bet for authentication on a non-domain joined server would be Basic or NTLM. With NTLM you should be able to create local users on the report server and authentication as those. This is a very non-enterprise solution though.

Comment: Your question is unclear though - Azure Active Directory and Active Directory are two different things - should your question title be referring to _Azure_ Active directory? If you've made the decision to use on-prem Power BI Report Server, why are you using Azure Active Directory for authentication?